# IJulia package installation

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Is there a way around the following error when trying to install IJulia package in Windows 7 Enterprise?

```
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
INFO: Initializing package repository C:\Users\user01\.julia\v0.4
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error

ERROR: failed process: Process(`git clone -q -b metadata-v2 
git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA`, ProcessExited(128)) 
[128] in run at process.jl:531
```

Thanks

If I need to use a proxy, how do I specify that in the Julia console?

Comment: looks like the answer may be here on [git](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3001)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/W-H6ZxjXYSI).

Basically, (assuming you already have git installed) I had to run each of the following 3 lines from the Windows 7 Powershell:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
git config --global http.proxy http://<proxyuser>:<proxypwd>@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://<proxyuser>:<proxypwd>@proxy.server.com:8080
```

where: `<proxyuser>` is your username, `<proxypwd>` is your password, `proxy.server.com` is your proxy address, and `8080` is the proxy port.

Hope this helps.